# Is it good practice to use multiple namespace in same C++ source file?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I want to include more than one namespace in the same .cpp file.

While `std` is widely used, the namespace `z3` will be used in about 10% of a 25 KLOC file.

Will it be a good practice to use both as

```
    using namespace std;
    using namespace z3;
```

I am thinking of using only `std` and then use the `Z3` methods by mentioning the namespase whenever required. Like,

```
    using namespace std;

    z3::context c;
    z3::solver s;
```

Which of these is better practice?

I do not want to rename them into one namespace.

Thanks and regards,
Sukanya

Comment: if you write `using namespace r3` so why to creat it?

Comment: I'd start by seeing if you could somehow break up a 25K loc (!) file into smaller ones.

Comment: @Mureinik, Yes, I should do that. Have not come around to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's actually best practice not to import the entire namespace into your program because it pollutes your namespace. This can lead to naming collisions. It's best to import only what you are using.

So instead of:

```
using namespace z3;
```

You should do:

```
using z3::context;
```

Comment: Ditto with the contents of `std`

Comment: Thank you. That helped me decide. Thanks again.

Comment: Not only naming collisions. More dangerous is that code behaviour can silently change, for instance if both namespaces contain function with same name but slightly different parameters (overloading). See [this simple example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/578f9934725ffd90).

Comment: I learned two things today: To keep the files small and manageable. So, there is no problem in using `std::` at all occurrences.  This will make my whole project more streamline.   Thank all!

Comment: Where do the bloated programs come from?

Answer (score 6):

You may also use `namespace` where you actually need it, inside a function body for example :

```
void foo()
{
  using namespace std;
  using z3::context;

  // some implementation

};
```